# SQL Query when same date only show one separation

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to list all the rows from my database with the SQL query, from todays date and forward. And I also want to separate them by a DATE heading in HTML, but only one date by day.. Hope you're following, I'll give some more details below!

Right now my SQL Query look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM hours h
JOIN projects p on h.projecthours_id = p.project_id
JOIN users u on p.project_owner = u.user_id
JOIN projects_status s ON p.project_group = s.status_id 
WHERE h.hours_timeadded >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY p.project_id
ORDER BY h.hours_timeadded
```

The output code looks like this right now:

```
while( $row8 = $result8->fetch_assoc() ){

extract($row8);
echo $hours_timeadded;
echo '<a href=view_project.php?id='.$project_id.'>';
echo "<div class='results_container'>";
echo '<div class="results_id">
      <div class="statusbox status_id">'.$project_id.'</div> 
      <object><a href="my_overview.php?id='.$user_id.'"><div class="statusbox status_owner">'.$user_firstname.'&nbsp;'.$user_lastname.'</div></a></object>

</div>
';
```

And this is how it looks like in HTML, observe that the heading of 2018-01-04 is listed twice:

```
2018-01-01 
1123 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
2018-01-02 
1124 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
2018-01-04 
1125 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
2018-01-04
1126 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
```

This is how I want it to look like:

```
2018-01-01
1123 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
2018-01-02
1124 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
2018-01-04 
1125 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
1126 USERNAME PROJECTNAME
```

Any help or guidance would be super. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add h.hours_timeadded to Group by clause?

Comment: you can not use group by also bcz you are selecting the (*) all columns from all table... so here 1 date can be connected with multiple projects so the record comes multiple times...In script you can take date column separate & by mapping with  $row8 create new associative array & display the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the difference between what you get and what you want, it seems as if your SQL is getting the correct data.
What is missing is in the display code - you need to verify if you have already shown the date, and if so skip the date display line.  The below might work for that (if not, it should give an idea on how to get to the desired result).

```
$timealreadyshown = "nothing yet";
while( $row8 = $result8->fetch_assoc() ){

extract($row8);
if ($timealreadyshown <> $hours_timeadded) {
   echo $hours_timeadded;
   $timealreadyshown = $hours_timeadded;
}
```

Comment: Totally gave me the idea, and it works butter smooth! A huge thanks to you Koen!